# Java overriding method does not recognize variable defined in super

Tags: java, android

Finding a strange error with inheritance in Java (for Android) - I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but not sure what. My class SimonActivity extends GameActivity.

Within GameActivity there is this method that sets the values of a Map called gameVars:

```
protected void setGameOptions(Bundle extras)
{
    Map<String, Integer> gameVars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String difficulty = extras.getString(DIFFICULTY);

    for (TuningVariable t:tuningVars)
    {
        ...
        gameVars.put(t.name, varValue);
    }
}
```

Now I try to override this in SimonActivity as follows:

```
protected void setGameOptions(Bundle extras)
{
    super.setGameOptions(extras);

    winPoints = gameVars.get("winPoints");
    successBump = gameVars.get("successBump");
}
```

But when I compile, SimonActivity gives me the error "cannot find symbol variable gameVars"; the instances of gameVars in SimonActivity show up in red in Android Studio; and in GameActivity, Studio tells me that the contents of gameVars are updated, but never queried.

Obviously the overriding method in the SimonActivity subclass is not recognizing the gameVars variable from the GameActivity superclass even though I have run super. Why not? What should I change?

(I tried changing the calls in SimonActivity from gameVars to super.gameVars but that didn't make a difference.)

Comment: That's not how overriding works. `gameVars` is still just a regular local variable, and goes out of scope once the (super) method exits. You either need to return it, or assign it to a class field.

Comment: Try to edit the scope of gameVars, use protected.

Comment: You defined the variable `gameVars` as a local variable, i.e. its visibility and liveliness ends with the end of `setGameOptions(Bundle)` in `GameActivity`. Therefore, you cannot access this variable within `setGameOptions(Bundle)` within `SimonActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `gameVars` as a member of your GameActivity. You're declaring it inside the method call so they will be deleted as soon as your method returns. Also as far as I know an overriding method could not access a local member of the overridden method.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Because `gameVars` is a local variable for method `setGameOptions` (and exists only during its invocation).

### Solution

Declare it as a [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of your parent class:

```
protected Map<String, Integer> gameVars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
protected void setGameOptions(Bundle extras) {
    String difficulty = extras.getString(DIFFICULTY);
    for (TuningVariable t:tuningVars) {
        ...
        gameVars.put(t.name, varValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of gameVar is just that method in the base class.

Try making it a class attribute:

```
public class GameActivity{

protected Map<String, Integer> gameVars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
///...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make gameVars as protected. So child class can use it.

```
protected final  Map<String, Integer> gameVars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

You are using default.

From Java Docs - If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes).